# Need to inject model into services, Ember JS

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Need Help,

I'm really new to Ember and trying to get a Auth service working for login/out in CLI... However I can't seem to be able to call any of the handy ORM helpers without getting a undefined error...

I did get it working with straight old jquery ajax, but I really want to get this working with the rest adapter.

SERVICES/AUTHENTICATION.JS

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import DS from 'ember-data';
import App from '../app.js';
import User from '../models/user.js';
import ApiKey from '../models/api-key.js';

export default Ember.Object.extend({

//load the current user if the cookies exist and is valid
init: function() {
    this._super();
    var accessToken = Ember.$.cookie('access_token');
    var authUserId = Ember.$.cookie('auth_user');
    if (!Ember.isEmpty(accessToken) && !Ember.isEmpty(authUserId)) {
        this.authenticate(accessToken, authUserId);
    }
 },

//determine if the user is currently authenticated
isAuthenticated: function() {
    return !Ember.isEmpty(this.get('apiKey.accessToken')) &&       !Ember.isEmpty(this.get('apiKey.user'));
},

// Auth the user. Once they are auth, set access token to be submitted    with all
// future AJAX requests 
authenticate: function(accessToken, userId) {
    Ember.$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken }
    });
    user = User.find(userId)
    this.set('apiKey', ApiKey.create({
     accessToken: accessToken,
     user: user
    }));
   },

   //log out the user 
   reset: function({
App.__container__.lookup('route:application').transitionTo('session.new');
    Ember.run.sync();
    Ember.run.next('apiKey', null);
    Ember.$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: { 'Authorization' : 'Bearer none' }
    });
},

// Ensure that when the browser the cookies are refreshed 
apiKeyObserver: function() {
    if (Ember.isEmpty(this.get('apiKey'))) {
        Ember.$.removeCookie('access_token');
        Ember.$.removeCookie('auth_user');
    } else {
        Ember.$.cookie('access_token', this.get('apiKey.accessToken'));
        Ember.$.cookie('auth_user', this.get('apiKey.user.id'));
    }
}
});

// // Reset the authentication if any ember data request returns a 401     unauthorized error
DS.rejectionHandler = function(reason) {
  if (reason.status === 401) {
    App.AuthManager.reset();
  }
throw reason;
};
```

Comment: You are trying to inject the code of the model, not the instance. try with this.store.find('user')

Comment: Vaibhav's comment is correct. I'd also recommend using [ember-simple-auth](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth) with does exactly what you are doing but also comes with a bunch of nice things for free! I decided to use it after 6 months into my project and I wish I had found it earlier :)

Comment: Thanks guys. I checked out ember-simple-auth repository and it seems like a way better solution!

Comment: Consider answering your question if you've found a solution.

Comment: Valibhav solution worked:) However for simplicity I decided to go for ember-simple-auth as my auth provider!